# Are there any built-in functions to find the feasible space for a set of constraints?

Tags: plotting, constraint

I have a set of constants including linear and nonlinear equalities and inequalities. How can I obtain the the admissible values of each dimension (so-called feasible solution space) . 
Are there any built-in *Mathematica* functions that can solve these constraints together and find the feasible space?

For example, assume these constraints:

```
2 == x1 + x2 - x3 - x4/2 + x5;
0 == 4 x1 - 2 x2 + 8 x3/10 + 6 x4/10 + x5^2/2;
(10 <= x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2);
```

Also, how could I plot the solution space if the number of dimensions were less than three?

Comment: Please post Mathematica code, not formulas. And if possible, without subscripts

Comment: I am not using Mathematica, I am matlab user. But I know most mathematicians use this programe. so I thought to ask my question here and when I got the answer, convert their codes to matlab. or at least I can get the gist of solving such problem. So, if that helps, Please edit my question with Mathematica code. Thanks @belisarius

Comment: So yours is a question about mathematics, not Mathematica(TM). And I doubt _most_ mathematicians are using this program. Sorry.

Comment: You may ask questions about matlab on stackoverflow.com

Comment: I posted this question on math forum already, but it didn't get any attention, so I was checking my chance here. Also, I tried this forum for other reason before and I got good results @belisarius

Comment: Please consider that this forum is _only_ for Mathematica questions. And a Mathematica answer won't help you. In any case, here it is `eq1 = 2 == x1 + x2 - x3 - x4/2 + x5; eq2 = 0 == 4 x1 - 2 x2 + 8 x3/10 + 6 x4/10 + x5^2/2; eq3 = (10 <= x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2); Solve[{eq1 && eq2 && eq3}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}] `

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question :) @belisarius

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the issue it raises is not a  _Mathematica_ issue but a mathematics one. That it is formulated in terms of _Mathematica_ is not sufficient to make it an appropriate question for _Mathematica_.SE.

Comment: The question is edited and elucidated. Thanks for your comment @m_goldberg

Comment: The answer resulting from Belisarius' input is pretty large and consists of objects that you won't be able to use outside of Mathematica (Root objects and ConditionalExpression-s), so this won't help you very much.

Comment: Bad times, So what should I do @SjoerdC.deVries ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for[`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html). It will find the solution space for your example problem.

```
Reduce[
  {2 == x1 + x2 - x3 - x4/2 + x5,
   0 == 4 x1 - 2 x2 + 8 x3/10 + 6 x4/10 + x5^2/2,
   10 <= x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2}, 
  {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}, Reals]
```

It produces a very large result, but does so rather quickly, The result is too large to display in this answer. You will have to run *Mathematica* to see it and decide for yourself if the result will of any use to you.

Comment: I do have *Mathematica* .But I don't know how to use it. I copy-pasted the piece of code you wrote in a *.nb file and pressed shift+enter. SO what should I do next? Also, lets assume x4 and x5 are zero. Is it possible to plot the feasible region? Thanks @m_goldberg

Comment: @Electricman with x4 and x5 zero the result of Solve is rather short and can be used easily (`eq1 = 2 == x1 + x2 - x3; eq2 = 0 == 4 x1 - 2 x2 + 8 x3/10; eq3 = (10 <= x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2); Solve[{eq1 && eq2 && eq3}, {x1, x2, x3}, Reals]`). The result lies on  a line so `RegionPlot3D` cannot be used here, but you can use the following: `Show[ParametricPlot3D[{2 - x2 + 1/12 (-20 + 15 x2), x2, 1/12 (-20 + 15 x2)}, {x2, -20, 16/63 (3 - Sqrt[51])}], ParametricPlot3D[{2 - x2 + 1/12 (-20 + 15 x2), x2, 1/12 (-20 + 15 x2)}, {x2, 16/63 (3 + Sqrt[51]), 20}], PlotRange -> All]`, ...

Comment: ... which uses elements picked from the output of Solve

Comment: I got the plot with you codes, But I didnt understand the second part of your code. :( @SjoerdC.deVries